# Sending data from a form to the parent component in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs

I have this `AddUser` component which which is a simple componnet that gets an email address, and a role from dropdownlist and then passes these two values to the parent component. Everything works fine other than one thing: if I first enter the email address and then choose the role it `onChange()` doesn't get the value from dropdownlist and pass null to the parent component. But if I first choose role and then enter the email, `onChange()` gets both values! How can I fix it?

This component has 3 props: `roles` is a dictionary and I'm creating `rolesList`from it to use it as data for `DropdownList` (it's from `react-widget`, https://jquense.github.io/react-widgets/docs/#/?_k=3fo3eq). The second prop is `handleChange()` that set the states of the parent component. the 3th one is`handleAddNewUser()` that returns the values from form to the parent component.

```
export const AddUser = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            email: "",
            selectedRole: "",
        };
    },

    onChange() {
        var email = this.email.value;
        this.props.handleChange(email, this.state.selectedRole); 
    }, 

    render() {
        var rolesList = [];
        for(var key in this.props.roles){
            rolesList.push(key);
        }
        return(
            <div >
                <form onSubmit={this.props.handleAddNewUser}>
                    <label >New user email address:</label>
                    <input ref={(ref) => this.email = ref} name='email'  type='email' onChange={this.onChange}  required />
                    <label >Choose a role for new user:</label>
                    <DropdownList data={rolesList} value={this.state.selectedRole} name='rolesList' onChange={selectedRole => this.setState({ selectedRole })} /> 
                    <button type="submit" >Add user</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    },
});
```

UPDATE: this is the code from parent component, `handleChange()` sets the states for parent component. `handleAddNewUser()` is supposed to use the states and make an ajax request to create new user. Right now it gets value for `newUserEmail` but not the `newUserRole`

```
handleChange(email, selectedRole){
    this.setState({newUserEmail: email})
    this.setState({newUserRole: selectedRole})
},

handleAddNewUser(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // using its state, it supposed to make an ajax request and create a new user
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the values from the submit handler if you want. [Here is an example](https://codepen.io/DriftDesign/pen/dvpZxM?editors=1111).

Edit: The component `DropdownList` doesn't create a real `select` form element, it just creates a bunch of `div` elements. This is why the normal `event.target` solution don't work. You do need a custom onChange handler for the component. Try the below. It will only set the state locally but that should be enough to get this data to any parent container. You haven't posted the code for `this.props.handleChange` so there is no way to know what args it can take.

Edit2: Added submit handler to call 'this.props.handleChange' with correct data.

```
export const AddUser = React.createClass({
       getInitialState() {
           return {
               email: "",
               selectedRole: "",
           };
       },

       onChange(e) {
         this.setState({
           [e.target.name]: e.target.value
         })
       },

       onSubmit(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         this.props.handleChange(this.state.email, this.state.selectedRole)
       },

       render() {
           var rolesList = [];
           for(var key in this.props.roles){
               rolesList.push(key);
           }
           return(
               <div >
                   <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                       <label >New user email address:</label>
                       <input ref={(ref) => this.email = ref} name='email'  type='email' onChange={this.onChange}  required />
                       <label >Choose a role for new user:</label>
                       <DropdownList ref={(ref) => this.role = ref} data={rolesList} value={this.state.selectedRole} name='rolesList' onChange={selectedRole => this.setState({ selectedRole })} /> 
                       <button type="submit" >Add user</button>
                   </form>
               </div>
           );
       },
   });
```

Note that `this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })` using square brackets like this is a way to set the object key without knowing the name ahead of time. In this case is will be whatever the name prop of the element is (email).

Comment: I just tried it. If I write `onSubmit`exactly the same as your answer, it adds the email address to the address bar and not the role: `?email=tes%40test.com`. Also, I don't want it that way. I need it to send the data from form to the parent and set the parents states. I added `e.preventDefault()` to `onSubmit` and it still complains about not knowing `value` here: `const role = e.target.role.value;`

Comment: I forgot to add `e.preventDefault()` thanks for pointing that out. You need to use the same name you have for you form element, `e.target.rolesList.value` in this case. You should be able to the state of the parent in the `handleAddNewUser` method that you pass down as props. Something like `data => this.setState(data)`, if you post the code for the parent it would help.

Comment: yeah, that's what I did, just made a mistake in my previous comment. Using `const role = e.target.rolesList.value;` returns this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`

Comment: Having had a look at react-widget the `DropdownList` component doesn't actually create a select box, it is a bunch of div's. That's why this does't work. I will update the answer.

Comment: I just added the parent component methods to the question. Can you please tell me what is happening here: `this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })` . I don't get it

Comment: When you set an object key like this it uses a variable name. So this is the same as `setState({ email: e.target.value })`.

Comment: Yeay!! Thanks, it finally worked! You just need to edit your answer and change `onSubmit` to get an event and then `e.preventDefault();`. Also, I removed unnecessary parts from dropdownlist: `<DropdownList data={rolesList}  onChange={selectedRole => this.setState({ selectedRole })} /> `

Answer (score 0):

You only call `this.onChange()` when email input value changes.

So even on the first character you type the `this.onChange` sends the email value and the `this.role.value` which is `''`.

So add an `if()` to check if `role` has a valid value.

to check for `role.value` inside `onChange()`

```
if(email.length > 0 && role.length > 0)
    this.props.handleChange(email, role);
```

Comment: the problem is it doesn't understand `this.role.value` and I'm getting this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`